# Swift protocol for things that convert to and from String

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, rawrepresentable

I'd like to have a `GenericThing` with a template parameter that is any type that can sensibly be converted to and from a string.

```
// ConvertsToAndFromString is a made up protocol here – what should I use instead?
struct GenericThing<Id: ConvertsToAndFromString> {
}
```

I should then be able to use `GenericThing` with any type that has a reasonable encoding as a string. For example, it should work for `Int`, `String` (well, dah), and ideally, any `RawRepresentable` where the `RawValue` itself will convert to and from a string.

Example:

```
enum Tubbies: String {
  case dipsy
  case laalaa
  case po
}

// I'd like to be able to do this.
let genericThing = GenericThing<Tubbies>
```

I can't see how to easily do this.

I was hoping I could use `LosslessStringConvertible` instead of my made up `ConvertsToAndFromString`.

I tried this, and it works for `Int` and such. But it doesn't work for `Tubbies`. I couldn't see a way to make all `RawRepresentable` where `RawValue: LosslessStringConvertible` also conform to `LosslessStringConvertible`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you extend `RawRespresentable` to be conditionally `LosslessStringConvertible` depending on its `RawValue`:

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: LosslessStringConvertible {
    init?(_ rv: RawValue) {
        self.init(rawValue: rv)
    }

    var description: String { return self.rawValue.description }
}
```

Here it is in action:

```
struct GenericThing<Id: LosslessStringConvertible> {

}

enum Tubbies: String, LosslessStringConvertible {
    case dipsy
    case laalaa
    case po
}

let genericThing = GenericThing<Tubbies>()
print(Tubbies.po is LosslessStringConvertible) // => true
```

Comment: :-) Brilliant, thank you! … I should also ask, is there any obvious risk with extending all `RawRepresentable` in this way? I'm grinning because I got this answer slightly after asking the question, but I'm glad you confirmed it and you got the first answer in!

Comment: @Benjohn You could run into issues is somebody else defined the same conformance in a library you've imported, but generally, that kind of thing is rare enough that I don't let it hold me back from writing the code I would like. "cross that bridge when you get there", you know?

Comment: `var description: String {  .init(rawValue) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Eh, I'm not a fan. I like the clarity that simply being `description` being passed through, uneffected

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/1539130-description

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not sure I get your point. Are you trying to point out the part where it says it's discouraged to be called?

Comment: Yes if you can avoid it why not

Comment: Because avoiding it comes to no benefit here, and only makes this code more indirect and less clear. The whole point of this adapter pattern is to forward onto the existing `LosslessStringConvertible` APIs, one of which is the `description` property inherited from `CustomStringConvertible`. Calling the `String` initializer works, but it's ultimately point is to call `description` for you. Your code is still depending on that happening, even though it doesn't express it explicitly. So you're no less coupled to `description`, you've just hidden the coupling behind `String.init`

Comment: This seems to break the `CodingKey` protocol used for `Codable` objects. It causes the compilation error: `Type 'Test.CodingKeys' does not conform to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'`

Comment: @Joe I don't really know what you're talking about. Please open a new post and add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue in Swift 5.2 at least where extending `RawRepresentable` was causing `CodingKeys` to fail compiling.

```swift
public extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: LosslessStringConvertible {
    init?(_ rv: RawValue) { self.init(rawValue: rv) }
    var description: String { rawValue.description }
}

struct Test: Codable {
    public var test: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { // Error: Type 'Test.CodingKeys' does not conform to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'
        case test = "foo"
    } 
}
```

My workaround was to instead explicitly add conformance using the same strategy, it requires being able to change the enum but allows `CodingKeys` to compile.

```swift
public protocol LosslessStringConvertibleEnum: LosslessStringConvertible, 
    RawRepresentable where RawValue: LosslessStringConvertible {}

public extension LosslessStringConvertibleEnum {
    init?(_ rawValue: RawValue) { self.init(rawValue: rawValue) }
    var description: String { rawValue.description }
}

enum Tubbies: String, LosslessStringConvertibleEnum {
    case dipsy
    case laalaa
    case po
}
```